# Jasmine to run with firefoxdriver on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jasmine, firefox-driver

I am trying to run jasmine to run with firefoxdriver and getting this error.
I am using os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_25'

```
21:57:46 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.searls:jasmine-maven-plugin:2.0:test (default) on project xxxx: The jasmine-maven-plugin encountered an exception:
21:57:46 [ERROR] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
21:57:46 [ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.driver.WebDriverFactory.createCustomWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:99)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.driver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:72)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.mojo.TestMojo.createDriver(TestMojo.java:260)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.mojo.TestMojo.executeSpecs(TestMojo.java:235)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.mojo.TestMojo.run(TestMojo.java:204)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.mojo.AbstractJasmineMojo.execute(AbstractJasmineMojo.java:385)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.mojo.TestMojo.execute(TestMojo.java:191)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
21:57:46 [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
21:57:46 [ERROR] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Bad request
21:57:46 [ERROR] Command duration or timeout: 94 milliseconds
21:57:46 [ERROR] Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
```

Comment: Which plugins and/or libraries are you using to run the Jasmine tests?